# Jquery multiple condition and not()

Tags: jquery, conditional-statements

This is working :

```
$('a:not(a[rel="no"])').click(function(event) {
    /* code */ 
});
```

This does't work :

```
$('a:not(a[rel="no"]), a:not(a[href="#tabs-1"]').click(function(event) {
    /* code */ 
});
```

I need to have multiple conditions, but it does't work.

How can I enforce multiple conditions?

Comment: You still haven't described what **it doesn't work** means! Are there too many elements returned? Are there too few? What is the expectation, and how does the result vary from that expectation?

Comment: [Here's an exmple](http://jsfiddle.net/nR8Zd/) that shows it working perfectly. Remember that `,` is the multiple selector. In other words it is an OR. So any `<a>` element that does not have `rel="no"` **OR** does not have `href="#tabs-1"` will be selected. Any `<a>` element that has **both** will not be selected.

Comment: If you wanted to select elements that have neither, you'd do this: `$('a:not(a[rel="no"]):not(a[href="#tabs-1"]')`

Comment: Thank you for quick answer. It's my first time here, and I appreciate. 

[Here is the solution](http://jsfiddle.net/maximel/MTE38/16/)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with RightSaidFred that it should "work" and if it "doesn't work", then we need more details. 
That said if for some reason it doesn't work for exactly the reason you think, then you can simply split your selector on comma, and combine results using [add()](http://api.jquery.com/add/) method.